# How to use CouchDB in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, couchdb

I want to create a web in node js with the using the "Sails.js" framework and "CouchDB" database. I have check its package and I found lots of package for that.

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=couchdb

So any one can suggest which package I can used for my application and also want to know for this I need to create a custom adapter.

If there has no requirement of create a custom adapter, so can I use the sails module feature.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular CouchDB adapter in JS :

- [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/)
- [nanoDB](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano)

---

They are both available on NPM.

PouchDB has a lot of features and his API is easy to use. It also supports a lot of return types (callbacks,promises, async/await). There's also a lot of plugins around PouchDB.

As for nanoDB, it has less features(since it`s minimalist) but it covers all the general features of CouchDB.

*Note: nanoDB normal implementation is with callbacks(which can be very ugly). There is an implementation of nanoDB with promises [here](https://github.com/romeovs/nano-promises).*

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look also to this adapter [sails-couchdb-orm](https://github.com/codeswarm/sails-couchdb-orm), but it could be no longer maintained. 
If you plan deploying your project using IBM Bluemix, you should try using [sails-cloudant-orm](https://github.com/carlosgalveias/sails-cloudant-orm). Cloudant is based on Apache CouchDB.